# Reject upload if file doesn't have valid text with Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

Admins can upload a file which should update certain tables. However, it should not be uploaded if the file does not start with /ZIPCODES/.

```
def validate_file_content
  file = File.readlines(Rails.root.join('test.txt'))
  file.each do |line|
   errors.add(line, 'not a valid file') if line !~ /ZIPCODES/
  end
end
```

It should do something like the above, however it doesn't work. I can't upload any file since it throws the error everytime.

How should the code be written, that it checks if the file starts with ZIPCODES, it uploads it, and if it doesn't, it throws the error?

Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need other code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code scans **every** line of a file for matching expression ZIPCODES, but you need only **first** line. Try out

```
def validate_file_content
 file = File.readlines(Rails.root.join('test.txt'))
 errors.add(file[0].line, 'not a valid file') if file[0].line !~ /ZIPCODES/
end
```

Comment: Good catch! Didn't solve the problem but it was something I overlooked.

Comment: Sorry, try to change file[0].line to file[0]. That works for me